# Double click the left mouse button will appear c, how to fix this problem

Tags: python, edit-mode, selection-tools, select

Double click the left mouse button will appear c, how to fix this problem.When I in edit mode.It will always appear circle select.like this,I can't edit the bisect.Really need help.

[image]

[image][image]

[image]
edit in 11.17 2022
when i bought a Mechanical keyboard with 104 keys.this problem was solved.weird.
[image]

Comment: maybe check in preferences -> keymap what you did assign to double click?

Comment: I check in preferences many times.can't find the solution.

Comment: then pls provide blend file

Comment: by the way.i use macbook

Comment: How to provide blend file?I did't seem anywhere can do this@Chris

Comment: yep, me too. You could also try -> preferences -> load factory preferences because i am pretty sure you changed the keymap - maybe accidentally

Comment: just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions ...but as i am writing this...if it is your keymap - providing blend file won't help because these settings are in your startup file. So first pls load factory preferences.

Comment: where is load factory?It is strange，3 days ago. first time i open blender.the circle select always appear.but that time.i don't know what it is.I thought my computer was stuck.until now, i finally figure it out.then i search it in youtube but i don't find the answer.

Comment: in the preferences, in the bottom left corner, press on the menu button (3 white lines)

Comment: just a hint: as a beginner: NEVER try out shortcuts. Nearly every possible shortcut has a meaning in Blender and by this you can completely destroy your blend file because it looks like nothing happened but there might happen really worse things...i made this experience in my beginning of learning Blender too. Just press shortcuts of which you know what they do.

Comment: i do load factory preferences .but this problem still exist.maybe it's not because the blender preferences.it because my computer. i'll never figure it out

Comment: i am using a macbook too - it works. Maybe download another blender version? https://www.blender.org/download/. you could e.g. download an experimental version. Or an older version.

Comment: what‘s your version?i don't know.our macbook is diffent.Different chips. We're in different countries

Comment: I checked my computer's input method preferences and there is no problem, this problem only occurs in blender, maybe just because of the MacBook pro M1 chip. anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: in the first screen shot, can you search for "LMB" and show the results

Comment: @ShantanuAryan.I search for "LMB".There's nothing